# Usage of scale_y_continuous in ggplot2 screws with color fill in area plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to standardize some figures across different types of plots (line and area) and while the usage of scale_y_continuous works perfectly with line plots, when I use the exact same code on an area plot it screws things up a bit.

With the line plot I use the scale_y_continuous argument

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,1,by=0.2), 
                 labels = c("0.0", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, "1.0"), 
                 limits = c(-0.1,1), expand = c(0,0))
```

[and I get this as the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ3j2.jpg)

So I know that works fine.

[Then I try to use the same exact argument with an area plot and it screws the plot up in a way that I don't really have precise language to describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STMtq.jpg)

I'm not entirely certain what's screwing it up here, but if anyone has any input as to how I can remedy this error, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. At the moment, I'm having difficulty reproducing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though simplifying the code to:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,1,by=0.2))
```

resolved the issue.